# CPP DLL CustomAction code is not executing during installation

Tags: c++, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action, dcom

I have a Basic MSI project,in that I'm calling CPP Custom Action from DLL. But it's failing with following error.

> CustomAction  returned actual error code 1157 (note this may not
>   be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

When I checked in EventViewer, I got the following error.

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer  using
>   any of the configured protocols; requested by PID      94c
>   (C:\Windows\system32\ServerManager.exe)

I'm suspecting it's an issue with DCOM or VC++ redistributables. I enabled the DCOM rules from firewall as well, but still installation is failing with above error. Is this issue because of some corruption of system DLLs? How I can find the root cause and solution for this issue.

Comment: Are you certain that DCOM error you see in the Windows event log has something to with your MSI install?  I would be highly surprised...

Comment: 1157 is `ERROR_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.  How did you implement the custom action? My psychic powers suggest it's either a naming problem (you named the DLL with the CA one thing, but referenced in the installer as another).  Or the CA DLL is not properly exporting the right functions.  Or, and most likely, you didn't choose static linking for the C runtime in your DLL project settings.

Comment: yes I'm sure it's of related to CPP dependency issue. But how I can find it out. My installer contains one CPP dll and my CustomAction calling the functions from that dll. and it's get extracted properly.

Comment: What does `dumpbin /imports` and `dumpbin /exports` reveal about your DLL?  Preferably, your CA DLL is separate from the product code DLL and does not have any runtime dependencies.

Comment: My DLL has vc++ 2017 runtime dependency. I installed it prior to the installation of MSI.

Answer (score 2):

1157 is a dependency issue, and one of the easiest ways to get a complete list of dependent Dlls is the get the dependency walker program and run it on your Dll.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

You might have a dependency on the Universal C runtime, which I believe is separate from the VC++ runtimes. It seems to be a common problem because it varies depending on the OS and what updates have been installed.